# Save several data.frames in the environment of R using for

Tags: r, database, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to save data frames for different years using for. I want to save each data frame with a name and at the end name of name add the year. I have the following code, but I do not understand why it is not working:

```
(years_vector = 1988:2017)
(N_years = length(years_vector))
ind_year <- 1

for (ind_year in 1:N_years) {

   year=years_vector[ind_year]
   x <- data.frame
   name <- paste("data", year, sep = "_")
   name <- x

}
```

I can generate the names correctly and the loop, but it seems that the data frames are not saved on the environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need `assign` instead of `<-`

```
 ...
   assign(name, value = x)

  }
```

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
(years_vector = 1988:1990)
(N_years = length(years_vector))
ind_year <- 1

for(ind_year in seq_len(N_years)) {
        year <- years_vector[ind_year]
       x <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(10))
       nm1 <- paste("data", year, sep="_")
       assign(nm1, x)
}   

head(data_1988, 2)
#       col1
#1 0.9503611
#2 0.3362196
```